# Why isn't media query on max-width working?

Tags: html, wordpress, css, media-queries

I want to control the size of my logo using media query.

The original `width` of my logo is `210px`.

I want it to be `166px` when the screen `width` is greater than `56.865em` and same when it is less than this `width`, i.e., for mobile site.

I have written following code for this:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 56.875em){
  .site-branding img{
    max-width: 166px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 56.875em){
  .site-branding img {
    max-width: 166px !important;
  }
}
```

Only the first code block is working. Why isn't second working? (When the screen width is decreased, the `width` of logo becomes `210px` again).

Is there any rule that you can't use both `min` and `max` media-queries to control same element?

Comment: No, you can, I mean the CSS would still be interpreted as any other rule, just that what ever comes lower in the cascade order would take priority. But using the `!important` declaration should circumvent this. Could you provide a link to the site in question?

Comment: It also matters where in your code the media queries are placed. Make sure they appear last.

Comment: Can you post a snippet that demonstrates the problem? I mean, I can't duplicate the issue, obviously. https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/vgag3pd7/

Comment: Anyway, if you want the width to be 166px in windows that are smaller or equal than 56.875em and also in windows that are larger or equal than 56.875em, there is an easier way than using two media queries...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `max-width` rule won't work because it is overridden by the `min-width` since both have same value.

an easy approach, instead of doing `2 media queries` is simply setting the logo's `width` in the general CSS and then apply a media query:

- via non-mobile approach using the `max-width`

  or
- via the mobile first approach using `min-width`

### Option with `max-width`

```css
.logo img {
  width: 210px
}
@media (max-width: 56.865em) {
  .logo img {
    width: 166px
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/300/300">
</div>
```

### Option with `min-width`

```css
.logo img {
  width: 166px
}
@media (min-width: 56.865em) {
  .logo img {
    width: 210px
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/300/300">
</div>
```

---

### UPDATE

> First, I want the logo size 166px all the time.

So if you want after all is to have the logo's `width` at `166px` all the time, meaning you want to change the current `210px` to `166px`

Then you **don't need** media queries. Assuming you are changing a custom CSS file and you can't/want to change the Base CSS file (which contains the `width:210px`) all you need is to be more specific.

See more about  CSS specificity in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and in [W3C Specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html)

```css
/* emulating Base CSS */

.logo img {
  width: 210px
}
/*being more specific */
.header .logo img {
  width: 166px
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/300/300">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First, I want the logo size 166px all the time. So you need to edit it. Secondly it doesn't work. The .logo img{ width: 166px} isn't working at all.

Comment: really not working? have you tested both snippets?? both are working..and if you want the logo to be 166px all the time, why you said *I want it to be 166px when the screen width is greater than 56.865em* ? But hey if you want to be `166px` all the time why using media queries then?

Comment: Just FYI : Screenshots of [1st snippet](https://i.snag.gy/wkP7xB.jpg) and [2nd snippet](https://i.snag.gy/gDVOr8.jpg) working

Comment: Your code is correct but this method didn't solve my problem, because there were many existing CSS by WordPress. I just changed them and problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

This drove me crazy but I found that commenting out text before `@media` will block the statement.

```
<!-- DO NOT COMMENT LIKE THIS BEFORE @media -->
/* USE THIS Comment version */
```

Hope it helps someone out!